# EJS How to render variable inside a variable

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm trying to use the route to "inject" in the EJS the correct variable and using the same page.

1. I'm using a JSON to store data
2. I'm trying to dynamically call the correct information in the JSON file from the route using a variable to iterate it according to the defined route (cars/bikes...).

**Works**
<%= appdata.cars.deal %>

**Don't work**
<%= appdata.<%=product%>.deal %>

```js
router.get('/cars', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('cars-page', {
    product: 'cars'
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!
Best regards,

Comment: You don’t, you use normal JS bracket object property access.

Answer (score 1):

EJS executes embedded code as JavaScript, so you can access your data object in the same way as you would normally. In your example, this would look like:

```
<%= appdata[product].deal %>
```

Here is a complete example of using a value for `product` to output different data.

```
const ejs = require('ejs');

let template = `<%= product %> deal: <%= appdata[product].deal %>`;

const renderData = {
    appdata: {
        cars: {
            name: "Mustang",
            deal: "30% off"
        },
        trucks: {
            name: "Ford",
            deal: "20% off"
        },
    },
    
    product: "cars"
};
const output = ejs.render(template, renderData);

console.log(output);
```

Which would output:

```
cars deal: 30% off
```